# Conditional HTML entities in R documentation

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2, rd

I wish to include some non-ascii characters in the documentation for an R package, specifically the diacritic ă.
I am using roxygen2, so must not include any non-ASCII characters in the `.R` file from which the documentation will be generated.  Moreover, the non-ASCII characters may not be available to the software that compiles a PDF manual, so I wish to specify a safe fallback for the PDF documentation.

The obvious approach seems to be to conditionally display HTML entities, i.e. `\ifelse{html}{&#259;}{a}`, but the entities are evidently escaped at some point: the `.rd` file reads `&#259;` where I expect an `ă`.

Bonus points for answers that can be applied to diacritics included from `REFERENCES.bib` via the `\insertRef` macro...

Comment: Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47539862/1100107). Is it helpful?

Comment: Bingo! Wrapping the HTML code in `\out{}` did the job.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Stéphane Laurent's comment, the simple case can be solved by wrapping the desired HTML entities in `\out{}`, i.e.
`\ifelse{html}{\out{&#259;}}{a}`

For bonus points, it's possible to provide the appropriate PDF character with an ASCII fallback to be used if this is not available with
`\ifelse{html}{\out{&#259;}}{\v{a}}{a}`

It would be nice to think that when diacritics occur in references, it would be possible to create two bibtex entries, one using only ascii characters:

`\insertCite{\ifelse{html}{RefWithAccents}{RefAscii}}`

But this triggers a server error...